# How to negotiate for a second hand car that has been sitting on the dealer lot for months?

Tags: united-states, car, negotiation

I am interested to buy a BMW i3 in California and I saw that there are a few ones for less than $13000 that appear to be sitting in the dealer for months. I saw the very same car advertised for $16500 months ago and it even appears in the StreetView picture of the dealer lot already. I guess that the dealers that have a i3 must be desperate to sell them. For me these cars should be worth $9000 (Nissan Leaf has the same range and goes for $7000 in good condition). Would I be able to negotiate down to this value? How could I do this?

Comment: Almost half? Seems unlikely, but the longer it sits the lower they'll go. Make an offer, see if they take it... then wait as it sits longer... no magic.

Comment: As with anything else, just decide what the car is worth to you, and make them an offer.  If they don't accept, tell them to give you a call if they change their mind, and walk away.  Remember that while you may want the car, you don't need it, while they are losing money if they don't sell it.  You're the one in control.

Comment: @jamesqf -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper I agree, James could copy that into the answer section so that I can accept.

Comment: Are you sure the dealer actually *intends* to sell that car? A common sales tactic is to intentionally place some bad offers in a prominent place so their other offers seem better by comparison.

Comment: @Philipp There is more than one dealer in that situation. Search for BMW i3 on Craigslist on the SF Bay Area that you will see.

Comment: @Philipp I agree with you that they may also have a BMW i3 Rex on stock for a couple thousand more that they are moving faster. People go for the cheap battery model (that they know will never sell anyway) and go away with the range extended model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with anything else, just decide what the car is worth to you, and make them an offer. If they don't accept, tell them to give you a call if they change their mind, and walk away.

Remember that while you may want the car, you don't need it.  Even if you need a car quickly, there are plenty of used cars to choose from.  OTOH, the dealers probably have money tied up in that car, so are losing money if they don't sell it. You're the one in control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I kinda need a car, not necessarily that one, since I don’t have one right now. Since I’m not really in a rush, thus I will use this on my favor.

Comment: @Gabriel Diego: If you just need a car, buy a cheap used car (from a private party, not a dealer), which you can sell for about what you paid for it when/if you get the i3.